# Select multiple column in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am new to sql.
I want to view `id + ' ' + name` in ComboBox as `displaymember` and also `id` as `valuemember`, so sql would look like:

```
SELECT id, id + ' ' + name from tblproduct;
```

However, it doesn't work! i'm really appreciate for every one who can help me!

Comment: Could you post your frontend code?

Comment: Refer this link http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread6294-display-two-column-values-in-a-combo-box.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Try Casting Id to `VARCHAR`, give aliases to selected columns :

```
SELECT id AS Id, CAST(id AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + name AS IdAndName FROM tblproduct;
```

set `valuemember = "Id"` and `displaymember = "IdAndName"` in your code.

Comment: Well! column id's and name's type are nvarchar!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,cast(id as varchar(10)) + ' ' + name from tblproduct;
```

If datatype is nvarchar

```
SELECT id,id + ' ' + name from tblproduct;
```

If you want you can click the link below to see the demo.
[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/528a9/1)

Comment: Well! column id's and name's type are nvarchar!

Comment: then no need to convert just use + sign. Check the updated answer

Comment: it said like this:

Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 2 in SELECT statement.

Comment: make sure you have same collations for both the columns in the table

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query statement:

```
SELECT CAST(id AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + name AS Product FROM tblproduct;
```

It displays the result like:

```
    Product
    ---------------------------
    1 - Microsoft Paint
    2 - Microsoft Notepad
    3 - Microsoft PowerPoint
    4 - Windows 8
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem's reason is that 'Id' column's type is integer or uniqueidentifier.
if you convert id's type from int or uniqueidentifer to varchar, it will work

Comment: Well! column id's and name's type are nvarchar! it said "Conflict column 2"